# C++ issues with big char* when in release mode

Tags: c#, c++, string, char, release

I'm with some issues on C++ after I put my program in release mode.
I have a x64 C# dll, that I call from C++. The method that i call from the dll returns a stringified JSON, in this case with approximately 250000 characters.
When I'm in the debug mode in C++ I consume the result of C# dll without any issue. When I go to the release mode, I can see the result, but any operation that I do to them makes the program freeze and not responding.
I tried allocate the memory (char* result = new char[300000]), tried to copy char by char to a new string, tried to use strcopy but nothing seems to work.

```
using Calc = char*(__stdcall*) (char* Project);
HMODULE mod = LoadLibraryA("ExternalDLL.dll");
Calc Pos = reinterpret_cast<Calc>(GetProcAddress(mod, "Calc"));
char* result= Pos(Project);  //ok
string Props = "";
int sz = strlen(result); //freezes
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    Props += result[i];
```

Comment: Too many unknowns. Are you 100% certain that the returned array is is null-terminated? Does the returned pointer live long enough to be of reliable use?

Comment: What happens if you print out the result string character by character until the print loop finds a null terminator? Do you get the expected output?

Comment: If `Props` were truly null-terminated, there is no need for the loop or the call to `strlen`.  Just `string Props(result);`  In addition, if `result` is NULL, then calling `strlen` on a null pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: Maybe you can pause debugging and look at the call stack and the disassembly to locate the problem.

Comment: @user4581301 I check your tip, and i think that my string is not null terminated. 
My string as 257255 characters.  I made a while loop to count the chars on result char*. The program runs out of memory after count 780080 chars. That means that my char* is not null terminated. How can I fix that? 
In C# dll I return the result + '\0', but is not working. 
Anyone have a tip ?

Comment: Is any option on Visual studio that me helps to avoid this?

Comment: My C# is so weak that a toddler beat the snot out of it last week. Maybe you've formatted it correctly in C# but it's being mangled on the way out. Garbage collected or some-such.

Comment: @user4581301 the content of string is ok, but appears that in release mode the program can't see the end of the string.

Comment: Add the C# code (preferably a [mre] version of it) so that folks who do know the ins and outs of C# can tell you if what' you've got will actually work the way you are trying to use it. For all I know, the C# string goes out of scope and dies at the end of the function, giving the caller a reference to garbage.